# plotting a tree-map in python with area of rectangle representing value and color the label

Tags: python, matplotlib, treemaps

I want to visualize my data using a [tree-map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping). I have a dictionary with keys and values. How can I do it in python with the area of block representing the value and color representing the key/label. I saw a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282935/treemap-visualization-in-python) here.

But the [link](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/TreeMap) provided in the accepted answer plots tree-map on to a tree.

Example of a dictionary I have is. `{apple:1,mango:0.5,orange:0.5}`